# ASP.NET URL Rewriting in very easy way

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to know how to make SEF URL for web pages. After a little googling I have found many techniques, but all of them are so complicated. I do not need them. Is there any way to make SEF URL which is very easy to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download [this reference](http://www.urlrewriting.net/155/de/downloads.html) .

Then import it to your web site.

under `<configuration>` node type this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet" requirePermission="false" type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
</configSections>
```

The next step is typing the following code under `<system.web>` node:

the next one is putting the following line just before `</configuration>` tag:

```
<urlrewritingnet configSource="RewriteRules.config"/>
```

**We are almost done!**

Create a new .config file which matches the  tag's configResource parameter. I preferred "RewriteRules.config".

Then it is time to create rewriting rules on RewriteRules.config file:

```
<urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" defaultPage="Default.aspx" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>
        <add name="DetailPageRule" virtualUrl="^~/VirtualDetailPageName/(.*)/(.*).aspx" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/RealDetailPage.aspx?param1=$1&amp;param2=$2" ignoreCase=" true"/>
    </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

If you have more or less parameters you can change  the count of (.*)'s. Here there are only two parameters (param1 and param2), so there are only two (.*) strings.

Final Step is giving links in according to the rules you have created.

It is simple and fast. But I do not know if there are drawbacks  or any security issues.

Comment: I have encountered some trouble (404 error) after uploading to the webserver. I requested my host to make necessary settings then it is OK.