# URL rewriting in asp.net 3.5 withiout IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am working in as asp.net application which is in asp.net 3.5 version. I have a requirement to implement URL rewriting. I have defined 4 pages like

```
www.abc.com/page1.aspx
www.abc.com/page2.aspx
www.abc.com/page3.aspx
www.abc.com/page4.aspx
```

I want that when user types www.abc.com/language1 then 
www.abc.com/page1.aspx open. If user types www.abc.com/language2, then www.abc.com/page2.aspx should open.

Please suggest a solution to it.

Also, as this site is complete and have links sent through email to users ( and some of the links have querystrings) what is best way to redirect users to new urls without querystrings and generate new links using new pattern ?

I have gone through followig techniques:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite ( this is with IIS, can i use it with asp.net 3.5 and without IIS ? )

[ASP.NET URL Rewriting in very easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876329/asp-net-url-rewriting-in-very-easy-way) ( it is not tested for security issues)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx  ( This require existing links to change ? )

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new Route("language2", new PageRouteHandler("~/page2.aspx")));
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I make language2 dynamic so that It can be picked from database and still uses page2.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use anything strings like that:

    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route(mymodel.customstring, new PageRouteHandler("~/myphysicalpath.aspx")));

Comment: I see it is working in web forms but my images are not shown. I tried to add  routes.Ignore("img/{*pathInfo}"); and routes.Add(new Route("img/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler())); but still images are not shown.

Comment: does this work in 3.5? as per my information this will work in 4.0 and above only! Please correct if i am wrong..! I have tried this in 3.5 framework but it wont allow..!

Comment: Did you include UrlRoutingModule module in your web.config file? You can read at MSDN that it's working in .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this under Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax file, Check If Request comes from specified URL, then Redirect user to another Page, eg : if(Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("language1.aspx") , then Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx") .